# The Timer does not accelerate when it runs for the first time, but the timer accelerates at the next working moments. How can i fix it?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, runnable, multitasking

```
public void startCountdownTimer() {
         currentCountdown = startCountdown;
         //  stopTimer=false;
         if (stopTimer == true) {
             return;
         }
         for (int i = 1; i <= startCountdown + 1; i++) {
             task = new TimerTask() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     countdownHandler.post(doA);
                 }
             };
    
             countdownTimer = new Timer();
             countdownTimer.schedule(task, i * 1000);
         }
     }
    
     final Runnable doA = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             //reset timer when switching to another question
             if (currentCountdown != -1 && btn_next.getText().equals("CHECK") && stopTimer != true) {
                 if (currentCountdown == 0) {
                     relative_stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     
                     currentCountdown = startCountdown;
                     btn_next.setText("NEXT");
                     toast = Toasty.warning(getApplicationContext(), "Time's UP", 1000);
                     toast.show();
                     toast = Toasty.info(getApplicationContext(), correctAnswer, 1000);
                     toast.show();
                  

                     countdownTimer.cancel();
                     countdownTimer.purge();
                 }
                 tv_timer.setText("" + currentCountdown);
                 currentCountdown--;
             }
   
    
         }
     };
```

I'm trying to make a timer that counts down for 10 seconds, it works normally when it runs for the first time, and when it runs consecutively, the timer caused by delay suddenly speeds up.

Comment: Why are you initiating the timer inside this loop:  
`for (int i = 1; i <= startCountdown + 1; i++) {`

Comment: because countdown timer start from ten